# Flutter secure sqflite database using sqflite_sqlcipher

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I need to encrypt my Sqflite databse in flutter/dart.

I tried to use "**package:sqflite_sqlcipher/sqflite.dart as sql**" in my package
And attempt to create/open my database with a password

```
await sql.openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate,
      //onUpgrade: _onUpgrade
      password: "mySecretPassword"
    );
```

But while there is no errors the database does not get created as expected in the "**data/data/packagename/databases**" folder

Could you please supply an example of how to use this package in a normal database creation?
Or show where I go wrong.

Regards